# Livewire checkboxes selected by default

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-livewire

**What I would like** :

- By default check all checkboxes
- Get the value sheet id for later

First issue :

- Is it possible to sort / order them by id ?
  Because for the moment it orders them by the order of check.
  [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri5kZ.png)

If someone can help me I would be glad thanks :D

Here is my view :

```php
@foreach($sheets as $sheet)

  <div class="inputGroup">

     <input id="{{$loop->index}}" wire:model="selectedBoxes" type="checkbox" value="{{$loop->index}}" checked/>
     <label for="{{$loop->index}}">Feuille {{$loop->index+1}}: {{$sheet}}</label>

  </div>
@endforeach
```

Here are the results when I dd($sheets) :

```json
^ array:4 [▼
  0 => "All ValueRAM FURY"
  1 => "Non-ECC ValueRAM"
  2 => "All FURY"
  3 => "KSM (Server Premier)"
]
```

Here is my component :

```php
public $sheets = [];
public $selectedBoxes = [];

...
    public function readExcel()
    {
        ...

        $data = [];

        // Return an import object for every sheet
        foreach($import->getSheetNames() as $index => $sheetName)
        {
            $data = $import->getSheetNames();
            $this->sheets = $data;
        }
     }
```

Website view :
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv5DF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `checked` tag from your select and let `wire:model` do it's thing:

```php
public $sheets = [
        0 => "All ValueRAM FURY",
        1 => "Non-ECC ValueRAM",
        2 => "All FURY",
        3 => "KSM (Server Premier)"
    ];

// wire:model will ensure that all are checked by default.
public $selectedBoxes = [true, true, true, true];
```

and in your view:
(Take a look at the wire:model property and the checked attribute is gone)

```
@foreach($sheets as $sheet)
    <div class="inputGroup">
        <input id="sheet-{{$loop->index}}"
               wire:model="selectedBoxes.{{ $loop->index }}"
               type="checkbox"
               value="{{$loop->index}}" />
        <label for="sheet-{{$loop->index}}">Feuille {{$loop->index+1}}: {{$sheet}}</label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks again, with your code how do I get data from checkboxes ?

How do I add programmatically these in my readExcel() function : 
``` $selectedBoxes = [true, true, true, true];```

Comment: Instead of `public $selectedBoxes = [];` you write `public $selectedBoxes = [true, true, true, true]` . Then replace your blade view with my code. After that, you can access the value of the checkboxes with `$selectedBoxes[0]` up to `$selectedBoxes[3]`. These will then return `true` or `false`

Comment: I see, but if i want them to return for example the first one "All ValueRAM FURY", instead of true or false ?

Comment: Okey I managed to achieve what I wanted thanks again friend, I'll post it under.

Comment: By the way how do you validate such checkboxes to have atleast one checked ?

Comment: `if (in_array(true, $this->selectedBoxes)) { // at least one checked } else { //no box checked }`

Comment: For my case validating in the controller, but how can I validate if atleast one is checked
`protected $rules = [
        'selectedBoxes' => 'required',
        'selectedBoxes.*' => 'accepted',
        'rows' => 'required|numeric|regex:/^[1-9]\d*$/ix'
    ];`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Laisender I finded what I wanted.

What changed in my component :

```php
    public $counter = 0;
    ...

        foreach($import->getSheetNames() as $index => $sheetName)
        {

            $data = $import->getSheetNames();
            $this->sheets = $data;
            array_push($this->selectedBoxes, "$this->counter");
            $this->counter += 1;

        }
```

My view :

```php
                @foreach($sheets as $sheet)

                    <div class="inputGroup">

                        <input id="sheet-{{$loop->index}}" wire:model="selectedBoxes.{{$loop->index}}" type="checkbox" value="{{$loop->index}}"/>
                        <label for="sheet-{{$loop->index}}">Feuille {{$loop->index+1}}: {{$sheet}}</label>
                    </div>

                @endforeach
```